# How to display dynamic map using GDK?

Tags: google-glass

Is there any SDK methods to display dynamic map using glass GDK?

What is used for Glass navigation app?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps is used for that application if I'm not mistaken. However, there is no way to replicate it with a dynamic map because Google Play Services isn't supported in the GDK so you won't be able to get location information or get maps from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the GDK exposes a maps api the same way that the android api has the option to be compiled against the maps-inclusive version.

Having said that, it is possible to get the location, the same as you would on any android device (and if you are paired with an android device, that will likely be the provider of your last location fix). What you do with that is up to you, perhaps you thoroughly read the TOS of a mapping service, and make an api call to get a map image, and then display that (assuming that it's within the TOS of the mapping service). Perhaps you do something else with that data.

There is, unfortunately, no included maps API, to the best of my knowledge.